# libmpc - dyld: Library not loaded - Reason: image not found

Tags: c++, macos, gcc, homebrew, dynamic-linking

So one day my Mac refused to boot and I could only fix it by a reinstall of OSX Mavericks. Afterwards, my programming environment, which is managed by homebrew, stopped working.
First, I had to relink all formulas to get my commands back. Now when I compile a C++ project of mine, I get the following error.

```
cls ~/workspace/NetworKit $ !scons
scons --target=Tests --optimize=D 
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
g++-4.8 -o .buildD/centrality/Betweenness.o -c -std=c++11 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -fPIC -fopenmp -O0 -g3 -I/Users/cls/workspace/gtest-1.7.0/include src/cpp/centrality/Betweenness.cpp
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/libmpc08/lib/libmpc.2.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/gcc48/4.8.2/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0/4.8.2/cc1plus
  Reason: image not found
g++-4.8: internal compiler error: Trace/BPT trap: 5 (program cc1plus)
scons: *** [.buildD/centrality/Betweenness.o] Error -6
scons: building terminated because of errors.
```

What happened to the library, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved by a reinstallation of GCC 4.8 via:

```
brew reinstall gcc48
```

Comment: is this safe to do? does it affect clang?